# If $u\otimes v_1 = v_2\otimes u$; $v_1,v_2,u \in V-\{0\}$ then $v_1 = v_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

On the beginning I though that it was false. But, making several trials for counter-example I have failed in find one. Anyone has any suggestions to prove or disprove?

Comment: You mean $0 \neq v_1,v_2,u \in V$ ?

Comment: @André I edited, thanks.

Comment: I imagine that $V$ is a vector field over a field $k$, and that you're taking the tensor product over $k$? Else it is not necessarily true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Choose a basis for $V$ which contains $u$ as one of the basis vectors, and write $u\otimes v_1$ and $v_2\otimes u$ in terms of the corresponding basis for $V\otimes V$.

Comment: Let $B := \{u}\cup \{e_i\}$ such basis.
Then, $u\otimes v_1 = u\otimes v_1^ie_i = v_1^iu\otimes e_i$.
On the otherside, $v_2\otimes u = v_2^ie_i\otimes u$. I can't see yet, I am sorry.

Comment: That isn't quite right, because $v_1$ and $v_2$ might have $u$ terms when you expand them in the basis (so you have $v_1=cu+\sum v^i_ie_i$ for some $c$ which might be nonzero).  That aside, the next step is to use the fact that $\{b\otimes c:b,c\in B\}$ is a basis for $V\otimes V$.

Comment: humm, I got it now, I did not write $v_1$ in terms of $u$. Thank you! I will think about it.

Comment: thank you! I did it, and I concluded that the only possibility to it occurs is if the both are zero. So the statement is false! Thank you!

Comment: That's not right (and even if the only possibility was if both are zero, then the statement would still be (vacuously) true).  For instance, you could have $v_1=v_2=u$.

Comment: so I made some mistake, could you explicit a solution?

Comment: sorry, I know where I made the mistake. Yes, I must have $v_1 = v_2 = u$, that it the solution. I know why, I will explicit.

Comment: look at the answer I gave, is this right?

Answer (score 3):

Let $v_1 = \alpha u + \alpha_ie_i$, $v_2 = \beta u + \beta_ie_i$.
$$v_1\otimes u = \alpha u\otimes u + \alpha_i e_i\otimes u $$
$$u\otimes v_2 = \beta u\otimes u + \beta_i u\otimes e_i.$$

Then, $$\alpha u\otimes u + \alpha_i e_i\otimes u = \beta u\otimes u + \beta_i u\otimes e_i.$$
Then $\alpha = \beta$ necessarily.

$$ \alpha_i e_i\otimes u -\beta_i u\otimes e_i = 0 .$$
But then, $\alpha_i = \beta_i = 0$.

And then, $v_1 = \alpha u$, $v_2 = \alpha u.$

Comment: Looks good!  For a self-contained complete solution, you should mention explicitly that you are choosing $\{u\}\cup\{e_i\}$ to be a basis.

Comment: yes, yes, thank you! I just made a sketch, thank you very much! The ideas you provided are quite good! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

It suffices to show that $u, v_1$ are linearly dependent. In fact, if for some $\lambda \neq 0$ we have  $v_1 \otimes \lambda v_1 = \lambda v_1 \otimes v_2 $, then  $v_1\otimes(\lambda v_1 - \lambda v_2 )= 0 $ implies $v_2 = v_1.$

Thus, we are left to show that  $u, v_1$ cannot be linearly independent. Let $\Gamma: V\otimes V \rightarrow \mbox{Hom}(V^*,V)$  be the canonical map satisfying $\Gamma(w_1\otimes w_2)(f) = f(w_1)w_2$ for every $f\in V^*$ and $w_1,w_2\in V$.

Take any $f\in V^*$ such that $f(u) =1 , f(v_1) =0$. Such a $f$ exists, since $u$ and $v_1$ are suppposed to be linearly independent. Thus,
$$   v_2 = f(u)v_2= \Gamma(u\otimes v_2)(f) = \Gamma (v_1\otimes u ) = f(v_1)u = 0$$
is a contradiction.